# ActiveJob spec doesn't work with ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activejob

My test:

```
describe TasksCsvsController do
  describe '#index' do
    let(:params) { {'clients' => {'id' => ['1', '2', '3']}} }

    before do
      ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    end

    it 'enqueues tasks csv job' do
      get :create, params: params
      expect(ProjectsCsvJob).to have_been_enqueued.with(params['clients'])
    end
  end
end
```

The controller it tests:

```
class TasksCsvsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ProjectsCsvJob.perform_now(csv_params.to_unsafe_hash)
    redirect_to tasks_path, notice: I18n.t('flashes.tasks_csv_generating', email: current_user.email)
  end

  private

  def csv_params
    params.require(:clients).permit(:from, :to, tasks_grid: {}, id: [])
  end
end
```

And the ActiveJob:

```
class ProjectsCsvJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(clients_params)
    # it does nothing
  end
end
```

The test doesn't pass:

```
Failure/Error: expect(ProjectsCsvJob).to have_been_enqueued.with(params['clients'])
       expected to enqueue exactly 1 jobs, with [{"id"=>["1", "2", "3"]}], but enqueued 0
```

This is strange, because when I debug during the test, `params['clients'].to_unsafe_hash` is what I expect.

However, when I change the controller's line to

```
ProjectsCsvJob.perform_later({'id' => ['1', '2', '3']})
```

the test passes.

Comment: Why not use the normal strong parameters? `params.permit(clients: {})` using an empty hash allows any keys. If the structure of the params hash is known you should whitelist the allowed params instead.

Comment: @max That's not the case of the problem. I don't whitelist parameters, because there many nested hashes. I fetch each value explicitely, there is no danger.

Comment: If you are calling `deep_symbolize_keys` the hashes will not match since `{ "a" => 1 } != { a: 1 }`. I would just use strong parameters as i suggested or [`.permit!`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) since `ActionController::Parameters` declares a `==` method that matches a hash with string or key symbols. `ActionController::Parameters.new( a: 1 ) == { "a" => 1 } # true`

Comment: I repeat - it has nothing to do with strong params. I updated the question to make it clear - using strong params does nothing. I still have to call `to_unsafe_hash` because `ActiveJob` does not accept `ActionController::Parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior as documented in the [Rails Guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#supported-types-for-arguments)

You are trying to serialize a `ActionController::Parameters` object with `ActiveJob` which is not supported.

> ActiveJob supports the following types of arguments by default:
>
> - Basic types (NilClass, String, Integer, Float, BigDecimal, TrueClass, FalseClass)
> - Symbol
> - Date
> - Time
> - DateTime
> - ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
> - ActiveSupport::Duration
> - Hash (Keys should be of String or Symbol type)
> - ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
> - Array